# Dangling participle comma relationship

Tags: dangling-participle

Below text I have feeling that something is ungrammatical.Isn't the bold is dangling participle if don't put a comma after italic government?

By the way please don't put hold I am neither making you proof reading nor such stuff.I am confused and willing to learn.

> **I** too was a bit disillusioned as a computer engineer turned FBI cyber agent working inside the *government.* **Having** come from
>   private sector and now back in private sector, **it** is almost night
>   and day how far behind our government is with deploying innovative
>   technology to its mainstream users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence with *having* is definitely incorrect, and I think it is a [dangling participle](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dangling-participles), yes.  "Having come from" should modify *I*, not *it*.

However, you can't just run the two sentences together with a comma, because that would create something called a [comma splice](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/commasplice.htm).  They're two independent sentences each with their own main clause - *I was a bit disillusioned* and *it is almost night and day* - so you can't just ram them together with a comma.  When you join independent sentences, you need a semicolon instead of a comma, or a coordinating conjunction, or to make one a subordinate clause.

The best way to make these into one sentence would be to rephrase it so everything refers to the proper subject.  For example,

> I too was a bit disillusioned as a computer engineer turned FBI cyber agent working inside the government **;** having come from the private sector and now back in the private sector, **I found it** almost night and day how far behind our government is with deploying innovative technology to its mainstream users.

(By the way, it has to be *the* private sector - *sector* is a countable noun.)

Comment: The fix is where you add "I found it" or some similar phrase. You can join the sentences with a semi-colon, but that's not necessary to solve the problem. Another option would be to move the "having" clause from the second sentence to the first. You could say, "I too was a bit disillusioned blah blah the government, having come from the private sector and now back in the private sector. It is almost day and night etc". I think it would read more smoothly if you moved the "having" phrase to the front.